# ios logins using NSUserDefaults, handle crash or device shutdown

Tags: ios, authentication, nsuserdefaults

I’m trying to handle critical behavior when user login on my ipad application.

Once successfully logged in, we will remember the login using nsuserdefaults but will require a re-login when:

1. Crash occurred
2. Device was shutdown

is it possible to reset the login value on NSUserDefault when the above actions occurred ? if Yes how can I handle them ?

thanks

Comment: You should never ever store login credentials in user defaults. Use the keychain!

Answer (score 0):

For case 1 add an exception handler

```
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching: (UIApplication *) application
{
    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler (&myExceptionHandler);
}
....
- (void) myExceptionHandler (NSException *exception)
{
    // Make a note in your default settings
    // User needs to log in
}
```

For case 2 trap

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Make a note in your default settings
    // User needs to log in
}
```

Comment: For case 1 this is not a good solution. Better use a crash handling framework based on PLCrashReporter like QuincyKit. That can not only help you collect the crashes to your server or a service, but it also gives you a property to check if the app crashed in the previous run. One case cannot be handled though, which is if the app is killed due to excessive memory usage. Tracking the corresponding delegates won't help too, because they do not indicate if the process is going to be killed or not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way for an app to know when the device is powered off. If you meant when the application is exited read on.

Or just stick the logic in the

```
-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

And catch both scenarios.